# Why does new pages open the inappbrowser in my pwa?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'm developing a PWA. Everything works as expected right upto the point where I go to a new page within the PWA. When I open the new page suddenly the Safari inappbrowser bars appear - this happens when installed from chrome aswell.

I'm using Nuxt3.

Why does this happen?

This is my service worker:

```
const urlsToCache = ["/"];
self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
   event.waitUntil(async () => {
      const cache = await caches.open("pwa-assets");
      return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
   });
});
```